# Issue with downloading PDF via Puppeteer if it opens in a new tab

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, pdf-scraping

I am trying to download a pdf upon clicking a button.  But I am not able to download it as it opens in new tab and not downloading it.

Following Solutions I have tried, but nothing seems to be working. Please help me .

1) Listening to the `targetcreated`, and coverting the page to pdf

```
browser.on('targetcreated', async (target) => {
  if (target.type() !== 'page') {
    return;
  } else {
    let newPage = await target.page();
    await page.waitFor(5 * 1000); // To stop proceeding to other clicks in current page
    await newPage.waitFor(5 * 1000); // To let it load the pdf
    newPage.pdf({path: "./pdfDownloaded/" + new Date().getTime() + ".pdf"})
  }
});
```

Solution `did not work` as **converted pdf is blank**

2) Setting flag `always_open_pdf_externally: true`

```
puppeteer.use(require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-user-preferences')({userPrefs: {
   download: {
     prompt_for_download: false,
  },
  plugins: {
    always_open_pdf_externally: true
  }
}}))
```

Solution `did not work` as Chrome/Chromium **crashed** with `always_open_pdf_externally: true`

3) Giving print() in page evaluate, and as the print preview opens find the `save` button and click .

Solution `did not work` as it opens prompt asking location to save pdf and Puppeteer has no access to the Operating System driven prompt